# Get All Access Points Connected to my Wifi Networks

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

How can I get list of all devices(Mobile & PC) connected to my WiFi network. And How can I show details of the connected devices.

Comment: The short answer - you can't .. If you want more information, let me know :-)

Comment: Oh wait, I found something interesting - https://github.com/rorist/android-network-discovery

Answer (score 0):

You could read the /proc/net/arp file to read all the ARP entries. See the example in the   [blog post Android: Howto find the hardware MAC address of a remote host](http://www.flattermann.net/2011/02/android-howto-find-the-hardware-mac-address-of-a-remote-host/) . In the ARP table, search for all the hosts that belong to your Wi-Fi network based on the IP address.